# NARX Network using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there any solution to implement a NARX network with keras? How can I use the output of a network as one input for the following time step?

Comment: this tread seem to be the best for information and option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277119/example-for-narx-in-python-both-training-and-prediction